# Inheriting constructor in VS2013

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-studio-2013, polymorphism

VS2013 doesn't seem to have support for C++11's constructor inheriting, as stated here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

So the following isn't possible for me:

```
class Animal {
public:
    int age;
    explicit Animal(int _age) {
        this->age = _age;
    }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    using Animal::Animal;
};

int main() {
    Dog d = Dog(5);
}
```

Is there any workaround in VS2013 without hardcoding Dog's constructor to be the same as Animal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest you could do is just perfect-forward the constructor;

```
template <typename... Args>
Dog(Args&&... args)
: Animal(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
{ }
```

It's still not exactly the same as `using Animal::Animal` for some cases, but it'll at least get you all the `Animal` constructors and protect you from changes there from forcing you to rewrite `Dog`'s constructor every time.